# Is there a way for python to remember the last function executed in a script, and then call it again?

Tags: python

Say I have two functions:

```
def a(name = None):
    return "Hello " + name

def b(say = "something"):
    return "I will say " + say
```

What the functions do are mostly irrelevant right now. I would just like to know if there is a way to implement a `repeat()` function, which will repeat either `a()` or `b()` depending on which was last executed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may try to use some flag as a global var and set it in your functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that using decorators

```
latest = None
latest_args = None
latest_kwargs = None


def my_decorator():
    def decorate(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            global latest
            global latest_args
            global latest_kwargs
            latest = func
            latest_args = args
            latest_kwargs = kwargs
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate


def repeat():
    if latest is None:
        raise Exception("cannot call repeat without calling a function first")
    return latest(*latest_args, **latest_kwargs)

@my_decorator()
def a(name = None):
    return "Hello " + name

@my_decorator()
def b(say = "something"):
    return "I will say " + say

print(a("Bob"))
print(repeat())
print(b())
print(repeat())
```

Note that this may not be the best way to do so, it's just the first thing that come on to my mind, essentially, every time you call a decorated function, `wrapper()` will be called instead, which will save the function and the arguments, and then, `wrapper()` calls the function.